# "Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow" error while trying to create an adjacency matrix for a graph

Tags: python, graph, jupyter

I am working on a graph of the categories and subcategories on wikipedia and I'm trying to create an adjacency matrix for it
the dataframe looks something like this:

| NuCat    | NuSCat   | Ctg     | SCat
| 140790   | 83851    |Futurama | Categories_named_after_television_series
| 140790   | 94824    |Futurama | Comedy_Central_shows
|  ......  | ......   | ......  |  ......
|  ......  | ......   | ......  |  ......
|  ......  | ......   | ......  |  ......
|  ......  | ......   | ......  |  ......

1622625 rows × 4 columns

i tried the following code to get the adjacency matrix :
`df = pd.crosstab(df.NuCat, df.NuSCat) print (df)`
but i receive the following error message:

> 

```
ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to create a matrix of 1.6 millions rows by 1.6 million columns. I suspect you're going to have problems there. At one byte per cell that's 2.6 TB of memory.

Comment: and how can i get an adjacency matrix just for a section of the dataframe?

Comment: I'm not really a pandas person, but you're probably going to be looking at slicing up the dataframe before feeding it in.